# NSOperation: update UI after finishing task

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, nsoperationqueue, performselector

I've built up a test project with NSOperation and NSOperationQueue.
There is only one textbox: `@property (weak) IBOutlet NSTextField *textbox;`

In the background this is performed:

```c
- (void)main
{
    NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://google.com"];
    ASIHTTPRequest *request = [ASIHTTPRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [request startSynchronous];
    NSError *error = [request error];
    if (!error) {
        NSString *response = [request responseString];
        NSLog(@"MainThread: %@", ([NSThread isMainThread] ? @"YES" : @"NO"));
        [[AppDelegate sharedManager] performSelectorOnMainThread:@selector(pageLoaded:)
                                           withObject:response
                                        waitUntilDone:NO];
}
```

And the selector that is called on the main thread:

```c
- (void)pageLoaded:(NSString*)document
{
    [textbox setStringValue:document]; // does nothing
    NSLog(@"Textbox: %@", textbox); // returns nil
}
```

Why is textbox returning nil?

Comment: Did you connect the outlet in IB?

Comment: Yes, it is connected. Even if I call [textbox setStringValue:@"Test"]; from applicationDidFinishLaunching method, textbox value changes.

Answer (score 0):

Mmm, I have two ideas:

1. A **realistic** one: `[AppDelegate sharedManager]` returns different
   object from one you have called `applicationDidFinishLaunching` on.
   It's possible if AppDelegate is added onto the XIB + you have a
   separate singleton instance.
2. A **mystic** one: there is only one
   AppDelegate, but the property value is nullified somewhy. If this is
   the case, the simplest way to figure the thing out would be to
   change the "weak" to "assign" (to find out whether it's releasing
   issue), than re-define *setTextbox* to find who calls it.

But I can bet it's #1.

Comment: 1. On both places AppDelegate has same address. I'm really stuck on this one :))

Comment: OK, what about #2 - is the setTexbox called anywere? Also, I have another idea (#3) - the pageLoaded is called BEFORE the awakeFromNib. I.e. the actual view isn't yet loaded and the outlet is not set yet as well.